# Android with Firestore enabled: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: android, angular, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Firstly, I found numerous answeres to this question proposing to remove autentication in Firestore rule. Certainly it is not what I want.

My Firestore rule is

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, update, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

And I do want keep some level of authorization.

My Androoid code is:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        val TAG = "MainActivity"

        db.collection("transfer")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                for (document in result) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", exception)
            }
    }
}
```

Android project contains google-service.json download straight from Firestore

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "7953 *** 50",
    "firebase_url": "https://firetestjimis.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "firetestjimis",
    "storage_bucket": "firetestjimis.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:795 *** bb2ec8dc810f",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.example.demo"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "7953 **** sdu68ociuueir.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIza **** qHqOyrBsr_0cs_uq8"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "795 **** rkemu101gg0o.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

My final goal is achieve the same I have done with Angular but with Android/Kotlin. Just to exemplify, my working Angular code is:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  public transfers: Observable<any[]>;

  transferCollectionRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;

  constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth, public db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.listenSingleTransferWithToken();
  }


  async listenSingleTransferWithToken() {
    await this.auth.signInWithCustomToken("eyJ **** a custom token **** bdaG1Q");
    this.transferCollectionRef = this.db.collection<any>('transfer', ref => ref.where("id", "==", "1"));
    this.transfers = this.transferCollectionRef.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(action => {
        const data = action.payload.doc.data();
        const id = action.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    });
```

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebaseConfig: {
    apiKey: "AI yyy ihK3xs",
    authDomain: "firetestjimis.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://firetestjimis.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "firetestjimis",
    storageBucket: "firetestjimis.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "79 www 350",
    appId: "1:xxx dc810f"
  }
};

      }
```

So my straight question is: what I am missing to make above kotlin code atenticate properly? Maybe it is the same idea with Angular and I just have to add a custom token during call but how do it in Android/kotlin?

*** EDITED

NodeJs server providing a CustomToken suucessfully working in above Angular but I miss how do the same in Android/Kotlin

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.serviceAccount = {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "firetestjimis",
  "private_key_id": "ecfc6 *** e6661fd05923",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\ *** REMOVED *** ==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-fg6p9@firetestjimis.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "1024 *** 38150",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-fg6p9%40firetestjimis.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

 admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert(exports.serviceAccount)
});

var uid = "NSB *** 4DRo2"; //copied from https://console.firebase.google.com/project/firetestjimis/authentication/users
var claim = {
  control: true
};
admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
  .then(function (customToken) {
    console.log(customToken)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
  });
```

*** edited[image: Android Studio]

Comment: Where do you authenticate the user in your Android Application?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes, I am not planning to autenticate the user in Adroid. It will receive a CustomToken from an internal endpoint. By internal endpoint I mean NodeJs Server hosted in our DataCenter that will answer back to our Android App and then, with this CustonToken the App can start listen a collection document (you can see this working in Angular above). I edited my question adding the NodeJs providing the CustomToken although I don't thin it is relevant. Based on same Angular approach, do you know how to "signInWithCustomToken" and then  "snapshotChanges()" in Android/Kotlin?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes I just added a print screen from my Android Studio with evidence that the CustomToken is valied and it is signed in. But how listen/observe/snapshotChanges the collection document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my current solution. Hopefully it can help future readers. Please, take in account it is my first project both in Firestore as in Android/Kotlin. If you see some weird approach bellow please let me know it.

```
package com.example.demo
//https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity
//https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#kotlin+ktx

// Tutorial to CustomToken
//https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth#kotlin+ktx

//Tutorial to Snatshot Listeners and its queries
//https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#kotlin+ktx

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val TAG = "MainActivity"
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        auth.signInWithCustomToken("ey *** uHUrg")
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "*** signInWithCustomToken:success")
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCustomToken:failure", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(
                        baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }

        //val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("transfer")
            .whereEqualTo("id", "1")
            .addSnapshotListener { value, e ->
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e)
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }

                val transfer = ArrayList<String>()
                for (doc in value!!) {
                    doc.getString("status")?.let {
                        transfer.add(it)
                    }
                }
//                for (document in value) {
//                    Log.d(TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
//                }
                Log.d(TAG, "*** transfer: $transfer")
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your Firestore rules change from

```
allow read, update, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
```

to

```
allow read, write: if true;
```

this will fix the crash and missing permissions